# Removing if statement from loop

Tags: c, loops, optimization

I have the following loop in C that I am trying to remove the if statements from, so that they are not checked each iteration. I am struggling to do this however. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get them out?

```
for(ix=0;ix<Nx;ix++) {
  for(iy=0;iy<Ny;iy++) {
    if (ix==0) {
      pudx = (u[1][iy] + u[Nx-1][iy] - 2.0*u[0][iy])*(calc1);   
    } else if (ix==Nx-1) {
      pudx = (u[0][iy] + u[Nx-2][iy] - 2.0*u[Nx-1][iy])*(calc1);  
    } else {
      pudx = (u[ix+1][iy] + u[ix-1][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])*(calc1);
    }
    if (iy==0) {
      pudy = (u[ix][1] + u[ix][Ny-1] - 2.0*u[ix][0])*(calc2);    
    } else if (iy==Ny-1) {
      pudy = (u[ix][0] + u[ix][Ny-2] - 2.0*u[ix][Ny-1])*(calc2);   
    } else {
      pudy = (u[ix][iy+1] + u[ix][iy-1] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])*(calc2);
    }
    u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0*u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc*(pudx+pudy);
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at using "switch - case"

Comment: looks like you are special casing the first and last iterations of the loops... you should be able to change the loop test and initialization, and just use the else part of the statement inside the loops.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would properly indent your code.

Comment: Chances are pretty good that a decent compiler, e.g.  a late version of gcc, will take care of this for you.

Comment: @Gene, I didn't see a whole lot of optimization with -O2 on gcc 7.2.0.  The special casing version reduced the running time by 31% on my machine over the OPs version.  With -O3 I saw a 73% reduction in the running time.  This surprised me.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(ix=0;ix<Nx;ix++) {
    for(iy=0;iy<Ny;iy++) {

        pudx = (u[(ix+1)%Nx][iy] + u[(Nx+ix-1)%Nx][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])*(calc1); 
        pudy = (u[ix][(iy+1)%Ny] + u[ix][(Ny+iy-1)%Ny] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])*(calc2);

        u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0*u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc*(pudx+pudy);
    }
}
```

This is not an optimization. It just removes the if conditions as you asked for.

Comment: This may reduce the code size, but it will probably run slower than the original due to the addition of all of the remainder operations (which are essentially divides).

Comment: yeah.. i agree.

Comment: @TomKarzes But isn't a conditional jump one of the slowest things for a computer to do nowadays?

Comment: @Cppplus1 It depends on the processor, but I suspect division is slower on most machines, especially multiple divisions.

Comment: If `Nx` and `Ny` are both hard-coded powers of 2, then this code will most likely be much faster than the conditionally branching code. If not, it depends on the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution: take the `if` stuff out of the loops and make them more explicit. It's longer, but it saves you from potentially time-consuming branches and modulo/division calculations. I used preprocessor macros to keep things a bit cleaner and reduce the chance of copy-paste errors. The macros should be localized to the relevant code, else variables like `calc1` and `u_old` will result in compilation errors. Basically, you could replace your loops in question with the following code:

```
#define PUDX0 ((u[1][iy] + u[Nx-1][iy] - 2.0*u[0][iy])*(calc1))
#define PUDX ((u[ix+1][iy] + u[ix-1][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])*(calc1))
#define PUDXN ((u[0][iy] + u[Nx-2][iy] - 2.0*u[Nx-1][iy])*(calc1))

#define PUDY0 ((u[ix][1] + u[ix][Ny-1] - 2.0*u[ix][0])*(calc2))
#define PUDY ((u[ix][iy+1] + u[ix][iy-1] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])*(calc2))
#define PUDYN ((u[ix][0] + u[ix][Ny-2] - 2.0*u[ix][Ny-1])*(calc2))

#define UNEW(x, y, pudx, pudy) u_new[x][y] = 2.0*u[x][y] - u_old[x][y] + calc*(pudx+pudy)

// ix = 0, iy = [0..Ny-1]
UNEW(0, 0, PUDX0, PUDY0);
for (iy=1; iy < Ny-1; iy++) {
    UNEW(0, iy, PUDX0, PUDY);
}
UNEW(0, iy, PUDX0, PUDYN);

// ix = [1..Nx-1], iy = Ny-1
for (ix=1; ix < Nx-1; ix++) {
    UNEW(ix, iy, PUDX, PUDYN);
}
UNEW(ix, iy, PUDXN, PUDYN);

// ix = Nx-1, iy = [0..Ny-2]
UNEW(ix, 0, PUDXN, PUDY0);
for (iy=1; iy < Ny-1; iy++) {
    UNEW(ix, iy, PUDXN, PUDY);
}

// ix = [1..Nx-2], iy = 0
for (ix=1; ix < Nx-1; ix++) {
    UNEW(ix, 0, PUDX, PUDY0);
}

// ix = [1..Nx-2], iy = [1..Ny-2]
for (ix=1; ix < Nx-1; ix++) {
    for (iy=1; iy < Ny-1; iy++) {
        UNEW(ix, iy, PUDX, PUDY);
    }
}

#undef UNEW
#undef PUDYN
#undef PUDY
#undef PUDY0
#undef PUDXN
#undef PUDX
#undef PUDX0
```

This, however, is obviously intended for a computer to process, not for a human to read and later modify. The macros and comments are also an attempt to help a human should changes be required later. Unless there is a drastic performance issue in the original bit of code, I'd personally prefer the original loops with branching statements. It may be slower, but it's a lot easier to debug if necessary!

Comment: Those PUD macro bodies need to be wrapped in parentheses.  As it is, in the context in which they're used, they are implicitly relying on the fact that multiplication binds more tightly than addition.

Comment: You have a few semicolons missing.  Otherwise, I like the macros.  :)

Comment: @MFisherKDX Except they are unguarded.  Never write an expression macro as `(a)*(b)`.  *Always* wrap it in parentheses, as `((a)*(b))`.  That way there is no risk of unintended associations after expansion.

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault, can't figure out why

Comment: @WillC Sorry you're having trouble. The only thing I did was lift the case-specific calculations out of the loops. It was a simple copy and paste operation of your calculation lines. The macros simply allowed me to make it semi-readable, and I just double-checked that the proper args are passed to the `UNEW` macro. Where does it segfault?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote in terms of "prologue, main loop, epilogue" semantics.

```
void update_u_new(double **u_new, double **u, double **u_old, int ix, int iy, double calc, double pudx, double pudy)
{
    u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0*u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc*(pudx+pudy);   
}

//iterates iy=1 to Ny-1
void main_loop_iy(double **u, double **u_new, double **u_old, int ix, int Ny, double pudx, double calc2, double calc)
{
    int iy;
    for(iy=1; iy<Ny-1; ++iy)
    {
        double pudy = (u[ix][iy+1] + u[ix][iy-1] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])*(calc2);  
        update_u_new(u_new, u, u_old, ix, iy, calc, pudx, pudy); 
    }
}

void do_iy_given_ux(double **u, double **u_new, double **u_old, double *ux_m1, double *ux, double *ux_p1, int ix, int Ny, double calc1, double calc2, double calc)
{
    //prologue iy=0
    int iy=0;
    double pudx = (ux_p1[iy] + ux_m1[iy] - 2.0*ux[iy])*(calc1); 
    double pudy = (u[ix][1] + u[ix][Ny-1] - 2.0*u[ix][0])*(calc2);
    update_u_new(u_new, u, u_old, ix, iy, calc, pudx, pudy); 

    //main loop 1 <= iy < Ny-1
    main_loop_iy(u, u_new, u_old, ix, Ny, pudx, calc2, calc);

    //epilogue, iy = Ny-1
    iy = Ny-1;   
    pudy = (u[ix][0] + u[ix][Ny-2] - 2.0*u[ix][Ny-1])*(calc2); 
    update_u_new(u_new, u, u_old, ix, iy, calc, pudx, pudy); 
}

//assumes ix=0
void do_iy_ix0(double **u, double **u_new, double **u_old, int Nx, int Ny, double calc1, double calc2, double calc)
{
    int ix=0;
    do_iy_given_ux(u, u_new, u_old, u[Nx-1], u[ix], u[ix+1], ix, Ny, calc1, calc2, calc);
}

//assumes ix=1 to Nx-1
void do_iy_given_ix_main_loop(double **u, double **u_new, double **u_old, int ix, int Ny, double calc1, double calc2, double calc)
{
    do_iy_given_ux(u, u_new, u_old, u[ix-1], u[ix], u[ix+1], ix, Ny, calc1, calc2, calc);
}

//assumes ix=Nx-1
void do_iy_ixNm1(double **u, double **u_new, double **u_old, int Nx, int Ny, double calc1, double calc2, double calc)
{
    int ix = Nx-1;
    do_iy_given_ux(u, u_new, u_old, u[0], u[ix], u[ix-1], ix, Ny, calc1, calc2, calc);
}

int do_it(double **u, double **u_new, double **u_old, int Nx, int Ny, double calc, double calc1, double calc2)
{
    int ix = 0;

    //prologue ix=0
    do_iy_ix0(u, u_new, u_old, Nx, Ny, calc1, calc2, calc);

    //main loop on 1 <= ix < Nx-1
    for(ix=1; ix<Nx-1; ++ix)
    {
        do_iy_given_ix_main_loop(u, u_new, u_old, ix, Ny, calc1, calc2, calc);
    }

    //epilogue on ix = Nx-1
    do_iy_ixNm1(u, u_new, u_old, Nx, Ny, calc1, calc2, calc);

    return 0;
}
```